# Translate subversion username into a more useful name in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

It's a long shot, but is there any way to translate SVN usernames into more meaningful names when using Eclipse?

We have to use a repository managed by another organisation and our usernames are things like 'xy12345'.  I can teach our Hudson continuous integration server that xy12345 is actually 'Fred Bloggs', but is there a way to achieve a similar effect in Eclipse?